# I'm getting a connect timed out error in RabbitMQ in Socket

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rabbitmq, message-queue, spring-rabbit

I'm getting a connect timed out error in RabbitMQ.
Here I am getting this error for testing purposes. I am able to establish a RabbitMQ connection. If the connection cannot be established, I am trying not to get the error constantly.
If it cannot be connected continuously, this error is always repeated in the console. But I want to get this error at certain time intervals.
We perform this operation in java with thread sleep. How can this delay be achieved in RabbitMQ?
I tried giving the timeout in the configuration, but it didn't work. I am getting connection time out in socket connection.

[first place I got the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GO2zZ.png)